# laravel breeze インストールできない

Tags: php, laravel, bash, homebrew

**目標**
laravel breeze インストールしてログイン機能を追加したい

**問題**
laravel breeze インストールできない

composerのインストール方法
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
$ sudo mv ~/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer.phar'
$ composer --version

**試したこと**
1.composer require laravel/breeze --dev
結果　-bash: composer: command not found
2.composer$ composer require laravel/breeze --dev
結果　-bash: composer: command not found
3. brew composer require laravel/breeze --dev
Error: Unknown command: composer

Comment: composerがないといわれています。インストールの問題かと思われますどのようにcomposerをインストールしたのか手順を質問に追記してください

Comment: `composer --version` を実行した際は正常に動いているのでしょうか？ / 今回のような場合、質問としては「composer コマンドをインストールしたはずなのに見つからない」辺りの方が適切な気がします。

Comment: composerを入れ直したらできました。